# PowerShell DataTable delete empty rows

Tags: excel, powershell

I've stumbled upon some (DCOM) issues when using the `Excel.Application` object. So I've rewritten my function to read Excel files by using the `OleDbConnection`and `OleDbCommand` objects available within [AccessDatabaseEngine_x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). So there's no need to install MS Office on the server anymore and it's also more reliable I think.

It works great but the only thing missing is that I can't seem to figure out how to remove empty lines from the output of the function. I know it can be done by using `$DataTable[0].Delete()`, but I don't know how to determine if a complete row is empty. As it can vary in size depending on the input.

**XLSX-File example:**

```
Name     | Sir name
Bob Lee  | Swagger
         |
Jake     | Thornton
```

In the example above I would like to have the output only 2 (or 3 lines depending on the `$Header` switch), but I don't want to see the blank line in the output.

I found a [solution](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/46973/delete-all-empty-or-blank-rows-from-datatable.aspx) in another language, but I can't translate it to PowerShell.

**The code:**

```
Function Import-Excel {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [String]$FileName, 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [String]$WorksheetName,
        [Switch]$Header
    )

    Begin {
        # We can't read open XLSX-Files
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $FileName -Destination $env:TEMP
    }

    Process {
        $OleDbConnection = New-Object 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection'
        $OleDbCommand    = New-Object 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand'
        $ConnString = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='
        $ConnString += "$env:TEMP\$(Split-Path $FileName -Leaf)"

        if ($header) {
            $ConnString += ';Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";'
        }
        else {
            $ConnString += ';Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1";'
        }

        $OleDbConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnString
        $OleDbConnection.Open()

        $OleDbCommand.Connection = $OleDbConnection
        $OleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [$WorksheetName$]"

        $OleDbAdapter = New-Object "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter"
        $OleDbAdapter.SelectCommand = $OleDbCommand

        $DataTable = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable"
        $OleDbAdapter.Fill($DataTable)

        $OleDbConnection.Close() 
        Write-Output $DataTable
    }
    End {
        Remove-Item "$env:TEMP\$(Split-Path $FileName -Leaf)"
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the meantime, for anyone encountering the same issues:

```
Function Import-Excel {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [String]$FileName, 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [String]$WorksheetName,
        [Switch]$Header
    )

    Begin {
        # We can't read open XLSX-Files
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $FileName -Destination $env:TEMP
    }

    Process {
        $OleDbConnection = New-Object 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection'
        $OleDbCommand    = New-Object 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand'
        $OleDbAdapter    = New-Object 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter'
        $DataTable       = New-Object 'System.Data.DataTable'

        $ConnString = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='
        $ConnString += "$env:TEMP\$(Split-Path $FileName -Leaf)"

        if ($header) {
            $ConnString += ';Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";'
        }
        else {
            $ConnString += ';Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1";'
        }

        $OleDbConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnString
        $OleDbConnection.Open()

        $OleDbCommand.Connection = $OleDbConnection
        $OleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [$WorksheetName$]"

        $OleDbAdapter.SelectCommand = $OleDbCommand
        $OleDbAdapter.Fill($DataTable)

        $OleDbConnection.Close()

        # Remove empty lines
        $Columns = $DataTable.Columns.Count
        $Rows    = $DataTable.Rows.Count

        for ($r = 0; $r -lt $Rows; $r++) {    
            $Empty = 0
             for ($c = 0; $c -lt $Columns; $c++) {

                if ($DataTable.Rows[$r].IsNull($c)) {
                    $Empty++
                }
             }
             if ($Empty -eq $Columns) {
                # Mark row for deletion:
                $DataTable.Rows[$r].Delete()
             }
        }
        # Delete marked rows:
        $DataTable.AcceptChanges()

        Write-Output $DataTable
    }

    End {
        Remove-Item "$env:TEMP\$(Split-Path $FileName -Leaf)"
    }
}
```